# Grep - composite statements with separate context?

Tags: grep

Please consider the following example:

```
$ echo -e "-wordA \n 1\n 2\n 3\n-wordB \n 1\n 2\n 3\n" | grep -n -A1 -e '^-wordA' -A2 -e '^-wordB'
1:-wordA 
2- 1
3- 2
--
5:-wordB 
6- 1
7- 2
```

What I wanted to do above, is to have 1 lines of "after context" when `-wordA` matches at beginning of line, and 2 lines of after context, when `-wordB` matches. Obviously, my attempt doesn't work, since in both matches, I get 2 lines of after context.

Apparently, whichever is the last setting for after context, becomes the setting for all searches; but I just wanted to make sure - is it possible at all to use `grep` for such "composite" searches with individual contexts? (EDIT: in particular, I mean use by calling a single instance of `grep`, possibly avoiding temporary files)

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this with `grep(1)`. I believe I've written a little `awk` script that does what you want; try this:

```
$ echo -e "-wordA \n 1\n 2\n 3\n-wordB \n 1\n 2\n 3\n" |
  awk '/^-wordA/ {print; getline; print;}
       /^-wordB/ {print; getline; print; getline; print;}'
-wordA 
 1
-wordB 
 1
 2
$
```

I've arbitrarily line-wrapped for legibility -- you'll need to make it all fit, of course.

Comment: Thanks for that, @sarnold - looks great! I'll leave this question for a while, to see if a `grep` native answer won't appear - otherwise this answer looks acceptable for me; many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: That's a good plan; I don't know if this will Do The Right Thing if `-wordA` and `-wordB` are on back-to-back lines, or within the other's printing space. I assume `grep(1)` can handle that far more gracefully -- if it can be done in `grep(1)` -- but if not, this ought to be a worthwhile starting point.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with grep, assuming there is no output1 output2 files in current directory

```
echo -e "-wordA \n 1\n 2\n 3\n-wordB \n 1\n 2\n 3\n" | tee >(grep -n -A1 -e '^-wordA' >output1) >(grep -n -A2 -e '^-wordB' >output2) >/dev/null ; cat output1 output2
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @NahuelFouilleul - this solution calls essentially two separate instances of `grep`, and combines their results using temporary files; I was more interested in "native" use (implying single instance of `grep` (one-liner), and no temporary files); edited question now. Thanks again - cheers!